# Example of implementation of Baum-Welch

Tags: java, python, algorithm, statistics, machine-learning

I'm trying to learn about  Baum-Welch algorithm(to be used with a hidden markov model).  I understand the basic theory of forward-backward models, but it would be nice for someone to help explain it with some code(I find it easier to read code because I can play around to understand it). I checked github and bitbucket and didn't find anything that was easily understandable.

There are many HMM tutorials on the net but the probabilities are either already provided or, in the case of spell checkers, add occurrences of words to make the models. It would be cool if someone had examples of creating a Baum-Welch model with only the observations. For example, in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model#A_concrete_example if you only had:

```
states = ('Rainy', 'Sunny')

observations = ('walk', 'shop', 'clean')
```

This is just an example, I think any example that explains it and we can play with the good to understand better is great.  I have a specific problem I am trying to solve but I was thinking it would maybe more valuable to show code that people can learn from and apply to their own problems(if its not acceptable I can post my own problem).  If possible though, It would be nice to have it in python(or java).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's some code that I wrote several years ago for a class, based on the presentation in Jurafsky/Martin (2nd edition, chapter 6, if you have access to the book). It's really not very good code, doesn't use numpy which it absolutely should, and it does some crap to have the arrays be 1-indexed instead of just tweaking the formulae to be 0-indexed, but, well, maybe it'll help. Baum-Welch is referred to as "forward-backward" in the code.

The example/test data is based on [Jason Eisner's spreadsheet](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/papers/#tnlp02) that implements some HMM-related algorithms. Note that the implemented version of the model uses an absorbing END state which other states have transition probabilities to, rather than assuming a pre-existing fixed sequence length.

(Also available [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/1329976) if you prefer.)

`hmm.py`, half of which is testing code based on the following files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
CS 65 Lab #3 -- 5 Oct 2008
Dougal Sutherland

Implements a hidden Markov model, based on Jurafsky + Martin's presentation,
which is in turn based off work by Jason Eisner. We test our program with
data from Eisner's spreadsheets.
"""


identity = lambda x: x

class HiddenMarkovModel(object):
    """A hidden Markov model."""

    def __init__(self, states, transitions, emissions, vocab):
        """
        states - a list/tuple of states, e.g. ('start', 'hot', 'cold', 'end')
                 start state needs to be first, end state last
                 states are numbered by their order here
        transitions - the probabilities to go from one state to another
                      transitions[from_state][to_state] = prob
        emissions - the probabilities of an observation for a given state
                    emissions[state][observation] = prob
        vocab: a list/tuple of the names of observable values, in order
        """
        self.states = states
        self.real_states = states[1:-1]
        self.start_state = 0
        self.end_state = len(states) - 1
        self.transitions = transitions
        self.emissions = emissions
        self.vocab = vocab

    # functions to get stuff one-indexed
    state_num = lambda self, n: self.states[n]
    state_nums = lambda self: xrange(1, len(self.real_states) + 1)

    vocab_num = lambda self, n: self.vocab[n - 1]
    vocab_nums = lambda self: xrange(1, len(self.vocab) + 1)
    num_for_vocab = lambda self, s: self.vocab.index(s) + 1

    def transition(self, from_state, to_state):
        return self.transitions[from_state][to_state]

    def emission(self, state, observed):
        return self.emissions[state][observed - 1]


    # helper stuff
    def _normalize_observations(self, observations):
        return [None] + [self.num_for_vocab(o) if o.__class__ == str else o
                                               for o in observations]

    def _init_trellis(self, observed, forward=True, init_func=identity):
        trellis = [ [None for j in range(len(observed))]
                          for i in range(len(self.real_states) + 1) ]

        if forward:
            v = lambda s: self.transition(0, s) * self.emission(s, observed[1])
        else:
            v = lambda s: self.transition(s, self.end_state)
        init_pos = 1 if forward else -1

        for state in self.state_nums():
            trellis[state][init_pos] = init_func( v(state) )
        return trellis

    def _follow_backpointers(self, trellis, start):
        # don't bother branching
        pointer = start[0]
        seq = [pointer, self.end_state]
        for t in reversed(xrange(1, len(trellis[1]))):
            val, backs = trellis[pointer][t]
            pointer = backs[0]
            seq.insert(0, pointer)
        return seq


    # actual algorithms

    def forward_prob(self, observations, return_trellis=False):
        """
        Returns the probability of seeing the given `observations` sequence,
        using the Forward algorithm.
        """
        observed = self._normalize_observations(observations)
        trellis = self._init_trellis(observed)

        for t in range(2, len(observed)):
            for state in self.state_nums():
                trellis[state][t] = sum(
                    self.transition(old_state, state)
                        * self.emission(state, observed[t])
                        * trellis[old_state][t-1]
                    for old_state in self.state_nums()
                )
        final = sum(trellis[state][-1] * self.transition(state, -1)
                    for state in self.state_nums())
        return (final, trellis) if return_trellis else final


    def backward_prob(self, observations, return_trellis=False):
        """
        Returns the probability of seeing the given `observations` sequence,
        using the Backward algorithm.
        """
        observed = self._normalize_observations(observations)
        trellis = self._init_trellis(observed, forward=False)

        for t in reversed(range(1, len(observed) - 1)):
            for state in self.state_nums():
                trellis[state][t] = sum(
                    self.transition(state, next_state)
                        * self.emission(next_state, observed[t+1])
                        * trellis[next_state][t+1]
                    for next_state in self.state_nums()
                )
        final = sum(self.transition(0, state)
                        * self.emission(state, observed[1])
                        * trellis[state][1]
                    for state in self.state_nums())
        return (final, trellis) if return_trellis else final


    def viterbi_sequence(self, observations, return_trellis=False):
        """
        Returns the most likely sequence of hidden states, for a given
        sequence of observations. Uses the Viterbi algorithm.
        """
        observed = self._normalize_observations(observations)
        trellis = self._init_trellis(observed, init_func=lambda val: (val, [0]))

        for t in range(2, len(observed)):
            for state in self.state_nums():
                emission_prob = self.emission(state, observed[t])
                last = [(old_state, trellis[old_state][t-1][0] * \
                                    self.transition(old_state, state) * \
                                    emission_prob)
                        for old_state in self.state_nums()]
                highest = max(last, key=lambda p: p[1])[1]
                backs = [s for s, val in last if val == highest]
                trellis[state][t] = (highest, backs)

        last = [(old_state, trellis[old_state][-1][0] * \
                            self.transition(old_state, self.end_state)) 
                for old_state in self.state_nums()]
        highest = max(last, key = lambda p: p[1])[1]
        backs = [s for s, val in last if val == highest]
        seq = self._follow_backpointers(trellis, backs)

        return (seq, trellis) if return_trellis else seq


    def train_on_obs(self, observations, return_probs=False):
        """
        Trains the model once, using the forward-backward algorithm. This
        function returns a new HMM instance rather than modifying this one.
        """
        observed = self._normalize_observations(observations)
        forward_prob,  forwards  = self.forward_prob( observations, True)
        backward_prob, backwards = self.backward_prob(observations, True)

        # gamma values
        prob_of_state_at_time = posat = [None] + [
            [0] + [forwards[state][t] * backwards[state][t] / forward_prob
                for t in range(1, len(observations)+1)]
            for state in self.state_nums()]
        # xi values
        prob_of_transition = pot = [None] + [
            [None] + [
                [0] + [forwards[state1][t] 
                        * self.transition(state1, state2)
                        * self.emission(state2, observed[t+1]) 
                        * backwards[state2][t+1]
                        / forward_prob
                  for t in range(1, len(observations))]
              for state2 in self.state_nums()]
          for state1 in self.state_nums()]

        # new transition probabilities
        trans = [[0 for j in range(len(self.states))]
                    for i in range(len(self.states))]
        trans[self.end_state][self.end_state] = 1

        for state in self.state_nums():
            state_prob = sum(posat[state])
            trans[0][state] = posat[state][1]
            trans[state][-1] = posat[state][-1] / state_prob
            for oth in self.state_nums():
                trans[state][oth] = sum(pot[state][oth]) / state_prob

        # new emission probabilities
        emit = [[0 for j in range(len(self.vocab))]
                   for i in range(len(self.states))]
        for state in self.state_nums():
            for output in range(1, len(self.vocab) + 1):
                n = sum(posat[state][t] for t in range(1, len(observations)+1)
                                              if observed[t] == output)
                emit[state][output-1] = n / sum(posat[state])

        trained = HiddenMarkovModel(self.states, trans, emit, self.vocab)
        return (trained, posat, pot) if return_probs else trained


# ======================
# = reading from files =
# ======================

def normalize(string):
    if '#' in string:
        string = string[:string.index('#')]
    return string.strip()

def make_hmm_from_file(f):
    def nextline():
        line = f.readline()
        if line == '': # EOF
            return None
        else:
            return normalize(line) or nextline()

    n = int(nextline())
    states = [nextline() for i in range(n)] # <3 list comprehension abuse

    num_vocab = int(nextline())
    vocab = [nextline() for i in range(num_vocab)]

    transitions = [[float(x) for x in nextline().split()] for i in range(n)]
    emissions   = [[float(x) for x in nextline().split()] for i in range(n)]

    assert nextline() is None
    return HiddenMarkovModel(states, transitions, emissions, vocab)

def read_observations_from_file(f):
    return filter(lambda x: x, [normalize(line) for line in f.readlines()])

# =========
# = tests =
# =========

import unittest
class TestHMM(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # it's complicated to pass args to a testcase, so just use globals
        self.hmm = make_hmm_from_file(file(HMM_FILENAME))
        self.obs = read_observations_from_file(file(OBS_FILENAME))

    def test_forward(self):
        prob, trellis = self.hmm.forward_prob(self.obs, True)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(prob,           9.1276e-19, 21)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][1],  0.1,        4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][3],  0.00135,    5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][6],  8.71549e-5, 9)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][13], 5.70827e-9, 9)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][20], 1.3157e-10, 14)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][27], 3.1912e-14, 13)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][33], 2.0498e-18, 22)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][1],  0.1,        4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][3],  0.03591,    5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][6],  5.30337e-4, 8)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][13], 1.37864e-7, 11)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][20], 2.7819e-12, 15)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][27], 4.6599e-15, 18)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][33], 7.0777e-18, 22)

    def test_backward(self):
        prob, trellis = self.hmm.backward_prob(self.obs, True)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(prob,           9.1276e-19, 21)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][1],  1.1780e-18, 22)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][3],  7.2496e-18, 22)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][6],  3.3422e-16, 20)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][13], 3.5380e-11, 15)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][20], 6.77837e-9, 14)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][27], 1.44877e-5, 10)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][33], 0.1,        4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][1],  7.9496e-18, 22)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][3],  2.5145e-17, 21)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][6],  1.6662e-15, 19)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][13], 5.1558e-12, 16)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][20], 7.52345e-9, 14)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][27], 9.66609e-5, 9)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][33], 0.1,        4)

    def test_viterbi(self):
        path, trellis = self.hmm.viterbi_sequence(self.obs, True)
        self.assertEqual(path, [0] + [2]*13 + [1]*14 + [2]*6 + [3])
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][1] [0],  0.1,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][6] [0],  5.62e-05, 7)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][7] [0],  4.50e-06, 8)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][16][0], 1.99e-09, 11)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][17][0], 3.18e-10, 12)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][23][0], 4.00e-13, 15)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][25][0], 1.26e-13, 15)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][29][0], 7.20e-17, 19)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][30][0], 1.15e-17, 19)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][32][0], 7.90e-19, 21)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[1][33][0], 1.26e-19, 21)  
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][ 1][0], 0.1,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][ 4][0], 0.00502,  5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][ 6][0], 0.00045,  5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][12][0], 1.62e-07, 9)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][18][0], 3.18e-12, 14)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][19][0], 1.78e-12, 14)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][23][0], 5.00e-14, 16)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][28][0], 7.87e-16, 18)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][29][0], 4.41e-16, 18)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][30][0], 7.06e-17, 19)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(trellis[2][33][0], 1.01e-18, 20)

    def test_learning_probs(self):
        trained, gamma, xi = self.hmm.train_on_obs(self.obs, True)

        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][1],  0.129, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][3],  0.011, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][7],  0.022, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][14], 0.887, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][18], 0.994, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][23], 0.961, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][27], 0.507, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[1][33], 0.225, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][1],  0.871, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][3],  0.989, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][7],  0.978, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][14], 0.113, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][18], 0.006, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][23], 0.039, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][27], 0.493, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(gamma[2][33], 0.775, 3)

        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[1][1][1],  0.021, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[1][1][12], 0.128, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[1][1][32], 0.13,  3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[2][1][1],  0.003, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[2][1][22], 0.017, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[2][1][32], 0.095, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[1][2][4],  0.02,  3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[1][2][16], 0.018, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[1][2][29], 0.010, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[2][2][2],  0.972, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[2][2][12], 0.762, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(xi[2][2][28], 0.907, 3)

    def test_learning_results(self):
        trained = self.hmm.train_on_obs(self.obs)

        tr = trained.transition
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 0), 0,      5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 1), 0.1291, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 2), 0.8709, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 3), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 0), 0,      5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 1), 0.8757, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 2), 0.1090, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 3), 0.0153, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 0), 0,      5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 1), 0.0925, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 2), 0.8652, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 3), 0.0423, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 0), 0,      5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 2), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 3), 1,      4)

        em = trained.emission
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(0, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(0, 2), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(0, 3), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(1, 1), 0.6765, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(1, 2), 0.2188, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(1, 3), 0.1047, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(2, 1), 0.0584, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(2, 2), 0.4251, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(2, 3), 0.5165, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(3, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(3, 2), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(3, 3), 0,      4)

        # train 9 more times
        for i in range(9):
            trained = trained.train_on_obs(self.obs)

        tr = trained.transition
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 0), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 2), 1,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(0, 3), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 0), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 1), 0.9337, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 2), 0.0663, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(1, 3), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 0), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 1), 0.0718, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 2), 0.8650, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(2, 3), 0.0632, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 0), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 2), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(tr(3, 3), 1,      4)

        em = trained.emission
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(0, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(0, 2), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(0, 3), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(1, 1), 0.6407, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(1, 2), 0.1481, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(1, 3), 0.2112, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(2, 1), 0.00016,5)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(2, 2), 0.5341, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(2, 3), 0.4657, 4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(3, 1), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(3, 2), 0,      4)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(em(3, 3), 0,      4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    HMM_FILENAME = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) >= 2 else 'example.hmm'
    OBS_FILENAME = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) >= 3 else 'observations.txt'

    unittest.main()
```

`observations.txt`, a sequence of observations for testing:

```
2
3
3
2
3
2
3
2
2
3
1
3
3
1
1
1
2
1
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
2
3
3
2
3
2
2
```

`example.hmm`, the model used to generate the data

```
4 # number of states
START
COLD
HOT
END

3 # size of vocab
1
2
3

# transition matrix
0.0 0.5 0.5 0.0  # from start
0.0 0.8 0.1 0.1  # from cold
0.0 0.1 0.8 0.1  # from hot
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0  # from end

# emission matrix
0.0 0.0 0.0  # from start
0.7 0.2 0.1  # from cold
0.1 0.2 0.7  # from hot
0.0 0.0 0.0  # from end
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Great answer.  Your code is bit over my head but I'll spend the next few days trying to understand it(sorry i'm a newbie to markov models).  Thanks again!

Comment: @Dougal, can you please have a look at my question here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/96629/22327 ? thanks.