# When I attempt to run hmm.py in the Workspaces console it returns this message: NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am a beginner and need a code for learning Baum_welch. I found this code at link:[Example of implementation of Baum-Welch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958738/example-of-implementation-of-baum-welch), When I attempt to run hmm.py in the Workspaces console it returns this message: NameError: name 'file' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `file` built-in is Python 2, but not in Python 3; you will have to either update the code (hint: try to understand code *before* running it, so it doesn't delete your emails), or provide some substitute

> class file(object)
>   |  file(name[, mode[, buffering]]) -> file object
>   |  
>   |  Open a file.  The mode can be 'r', 'w' or 'a' for reading (default),
>   ...

For further information, see the Python 2 documentation.